# Parse json before array

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am studying. Please do not kick me )))
I was reading how to parse JSON from array to strings, but my document starts with 2 attributes and only then goes into an array.

```
"total": 56964,
"last": "2016-05-03 09:12:00",
"quotes": [
    {
        "id": 439124,
        "description": "Xxx: А давай какую-нибудь фирму заведем.<br>Yyy: o.O Зачем?<br>Xxx: Ну, у меня же аллергия. Кошек нельзя :)",
        "time": "2016-05-03 09:12:00",
        "rating": 0
    }
```

Here's my array "quotes".
How i must to handle two items before array?

And last. Array has 50 items. Best way to show this on screen is use ListView with 2 textview for "total" and "last" + textviews for each item in array?

Comment: This is not valid JSON - refer [this](http://pro.jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Valid JSON would look something like: `{
    "total": 56964,
    "last": "2016-05-0309: 12: 00",
    "quotes": [
        {
            "id": 439124,
            "description": "Xxx: Адавайкакую-нибудьфирмузаведем.<br>Yyy: o.OЗачем?<br>Xxx: Ну,уменяжеаллергия.Кошекнельзя: )",
            "time": "2016-05-0309: 12: 00",
            "rating": 0
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Well, i can download my target json. Would it help?

Comment: To parse JSON you require valid JSON. You cannot parse a random string as JSON.

Comment: I cant understand. I have link from my client. But i cant put it here. What can i do to receive help to me any way? I put here text only for demonstration of structure. I did not right?

Comment: I think so that you did not post the full Json format. please post your full json.

Comment: Provide the complete JSON you are getting from that link. Only then can anyone here be able to help you mate.

Comment: @Evgen your question isn't clear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @difyzz I want to know: 1) i must to handle two items before array? 2) Array has 50 items. Best way to show them on screen is use ViewGroup with 2 textview for "total" and "last" + ListView with textviews for each item in array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
               try {
                    String json = ""; // This should be the JSON from Your API
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    String total = jObj.optString("total");
                    String last = jObj.optString("last");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("quotes");

                } catch (JSONException jex) {
                    jex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

`jsonArray` now holds the quotes array, use a for loop and extract the nested JSONObjects one by one.

`total` and `last` hold the two variables before your quotes array.

As a best practise you can define your JSON nodes as private static Strings just after your class declaration:

```
private static String TOTAL = "total"
```

Comment: "total" should be an int or a double

Comment: Can you support me with displaying infromation? ListView?

Comment: You can post that as a separate question, it also depends on your use case - DO you want to persist data? Do you want to use a content provider so that your views refresh automatically when your datasource refreshes. However if you google a simple example for JSON to ListView in Android, I am pretty sure you will find a lot of simple examples from where you can build up. For a starter, check [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html) out.

Comment: @Skynet I used your solution in my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092206/nullpointerexception-in-line-setadapter-wrong-context But i did something wrong. Please impart a second to review.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gson to parse it to an object and then access the properties via that object. So that the "total" would be an int or a double. And the "last" would be a string. Then your quotes would be a List where object would have the properties of each json object item in the jsonarray.